# Random predictions from a multi-label image classification model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am currently trying to create a model for multi-label image classification using Keras. The model has 8 classes, with a slight imbalance in the dataset (some have 300~, whereas some others have 600~).

After weeks of playing around with it, I noticed that whatever prediction I get is entirely random - which led me to the conclusion that, possibly, I am doing some silly mistake without noticing it (my guess is that it has something to do with parsing the TFRecords, but I am not sure).

I tried multiple things: using different image sizes, changing the batch size, adding/removing dropout layers, increasing/decreasing the learning rate, add/remove augmentation - even allowing the model to overfit to varying degrees. However, none of these things made any difference whatsoever, and the model still makes random predictions. Possibly the most worrying thing - which led me to believe that I might be making a mistake with loading the labels - is that the results of running the same, identical run multiple times are vastly different.

Here is what I tried to do to load the files:

```py
def load_dataset(files, img_w):
    def parse_tfrecord(data):
        features = {
            'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
            'label'    : tf.io.FixedLenFeature([8], tf.int64),
        }
        tf_record = tf.io.parse_single_example(data, features)
        image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(tf_record['image_raw'], channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize(image, [img_w, img_w])
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) / 255
        label = tf_record['label']
        return image, label

    records = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(files, num_parallel_reads=AUTOTUNE)
    return records.map(parse_tfrecord, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)


def augment(image, label):
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
    image = tf.image.random_hue(image, 0.1)
    image = tf.image.random_flip_up_down(image)
    return image, label


def get_train_dataset(files, img_w, batch_size, n_train):
    train_dataset = load_dataset(files, img_w)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.cache()
    train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=n_train)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    train_dataset = train_dataset.map(augment)
    return train_dataset


def get_val_dataset(files, img_w, batch_size, n_val):
    val_dataset = load_dataset(files, img_w)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.cache()
    val_dataset = val_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=n_val)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(batch_size)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.map(augment)
    return val_dataset


def get_datasets(batch_size, img_w):
    train_ds_path = "/content/dataset/tfrecords/train.tfrecords"
    val_ds_path = "/content/dataset/tfrecords/validation.tfrecords"

    n_train, n_val = get_n_samples()
    train_dataset = get_train_dataset(train_ds_path, img_w, batch_size, n_train)
    val_dataset = get_val_dataset(val_ds_path, img_w, batch_size, n_train)
    return train_dataset, val_dataset
```

This is how I created the model:

```py
def get_model():
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(IMG_W, IMG_W, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=L_RATE),
                  loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  metrics=[AUC(), Precision(), Recall(), Accuracy()])
    return model
```

And this is how I trained:

```py
def train():
    early_stopping_cb = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=PATIENCE)
    model.fit(train_ds,
              verbose=0,
              validation_data=val_ds,
              epochs=EPOCHS,
              callbacks=[early_stopping_cb])
```

However, when I test, I get predictions that don't make any sense; there is no "preferred" class that gets predicted most of the time, or even a similar pattern that can be identified across runs - they are *entirely* random.

Just in case it should help, this is what I tried to do for testing:

```python
def test():
    for img_path in glob.glob("/content/dataset/test/*"):
        img = preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(IMG_W, IMG_W, 3))
        img = preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        img = img/255
        proba = model.predict(img.reshape(1, IMG_W, IMG_W, 3))
        top_3 = np.argsort(proba[0])[:-4:-1]
        predictions = []
        for i in range(3):
            predictions.append((CLASS_NAMES[top_3[i]], round(proba[0][top_3[i]], 2)))
        test_output.append((img, predictions))
```

Also - this is an example of the metrics from multiple runs, where the loss seems to shoot up immediately:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ40a.png

What is the reason for such random predictions?

**Edit**:

I added a large number or sample to make the dataset less unbalanced, but that did not solve the issue. Currently, each class has approximately 650 representations in the dataset - but the predictions are still completely random.

Comment: Could you provide a subset of your data to test your code?

Comment: Try again, by removing `sigmoid` activation function from final dense layer in your model definition and use `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` for loss function while compiling the model. Also refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#predict_on_new_data) link to understand model prediction.